# Como verificar a ocorrência de determinada string e retornar parte da mesma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Tenho uma pequena solução desenvolvida sobre a plataforma Node.js, no momento estou precisando verificar se determinada string existe, caso exista será necessário capturar o valor `INTEIRO` contido nesta.

Exemplo de string:

```
56 rows returned.
```

O valor numérico (inteiro) será sempre variável, porém, a ocorrência seguinte será sempre a mesma:  `rows returned.`.

Problema: como faço para verificar via regex se a ocorrência `xxx rows returned.` existe? E caso exista, retornar somente o valor inteiro.

Obs: lembrando que `xxx` será sempre um numero inteiro de valor variável.

O trecho de código acima faz parte de um laço de repetição, daí vem a necessidade de validar a string conforme descrito.

Comment: As respostas abaixo resolvem a questão do valor numérico, mas para saber se a string existe seria necessário um `if` extra. Porém é preciso saber como e de onde vem essa string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> como faço para verificar via regex se a ocorrência `xxx rows returned.` existe? E caso exista, retornar somente o valor inteiro.

Nesse caso, você primeiro deve verificar se a string está no formato indicado (fazer o `replace`, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/407772/112052), só funciona se a string já estiver nesse formato - ou seja, é algo que poderia ser feito **depois** que você já validou o formato da string).

Para validar se a string está neste exato formato ("número, espaço, uma string fixa"), dá para fazer com e sem regex. Seguem ambas abaixo:

## Com regex

Usando [expressões regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (regex), seria algo assim:

```js
let s = '56 rows returned.';
let matches = s.match(/^(\d+) rows returned\.$/);
if (matches) {
    let valor = parseInt(matches[1]);
    console.log(`valor=${valor}`);
} else {
    console.log('string não está no formato correto');
}
```

A regex usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim, eu garanto que a string só tem o que está especificado na regex (nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos).

Em seguida temos `\d+`. O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` significa "[um dígito de `0` a `9`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit)", e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, `\d+` vai pegar um ou mais dígitos. Este trecho está entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim eu consigo recuperar este trecho depois (conforme veremos a seguir).

Depois temos o trecho  `rows returned` (repare no espaço antes de `rows`). Ou seja, a string deve ter este texto exato depois dos números. Por fim também temos `\.` para o ponto final. Como o ponto tem significado especial em regex (significa "[qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)"), eu tenho que fazer o escape com `\` para que a regex entenda-o somente como o "caractere ponto final".

A seguir eu uso o método [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) para verificar se a string corresponde à regex. Se a string estiver um um formato diferente, o retorno é `null`. Caso contrário, ela retorna um array contendo os *matches* encontrados.

Como eu usei o grupo de captura `(\d+)`, eu posso recuperar esse valor com `matches[1]` - como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então é o primeiro grupo de captura, que fica disponível no índice 1 do array `matches`.

Como a expressão `\d+` me garante que só vai ter números, posso usar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) sem problemas, para converter a string para um número. No final temos o valor desejado.

O uso de `parseInt` pode ser opcional, dependendo do que você vai fazer com o valor. Se só vai mostrar na tela e nada mais, por exemplo, não precisa convertê-lo para número. Mas se vai fazer cálculos ou comparar com outros números, aí faz-se necessário o uso de `parseInt`.

---

Outro detalhe é que `\d+` vai pegar uma quantidade ilimitada de dígitos, pois o `+` significa "**uma ou mais** ocorrências" (no mínimo 1 dígito, sem limite máximo). Se quiser limitar a quantidade de dígitos para valores mais específicos, pode usar uma das opções abaixo:

- `\d{2,7}`: no mínimo 2, no máximo 7 dígitos
- `\d{2,}`: no mínimo 2 dígitos, sem limite máximo
- `\d{2}`: exatamente 2 dígitos

Use o que se adequar melhor aos seus casos de uso.

---

Outro detalhe é que essa expressão também acaba pegando números como `001` ou `0000`. Se quiser evitar que o primeiro dígito seja zero, pode trocar a expressão para `[1-9]\d*`:

- `[1-9]` é uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) que pega um dígito de `1` a `9`
- `\d*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de dígitos de `0` a `9`" (o quantificador `*` indica "zero ou mais ocorrências").

Assim você garante que o primeiro dígito não pode ser zero. Você também pode combinar esta solução com os quantificadores entre colchetes, se quiser limitar a quantidade de dígitos.

Mas essa regex tem outro problema: se a string for `0 rows returned.`, ela ignora. Daí temos que fazer outra modificação:

```
^([1-9]\d*|0) rows returned\.$
```

Agora ela usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**), com duas opções: um número que não começa com zero, ou um único dígito `0`. Assim, ela aceita `0 rows returned.` e `10 rows returned.`, mas não aceita `01 rows returned.` e nem `00 rows returned.` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/0JowC5/1/) alguns exemplos).

---

## Sem regex

Sem usar expressões regulares, você pode fazer um [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) na string, separando-a em partes, e verificar cada uma das partes.

```js
let s = '56 rows returned.';
let partes = s.split(' ');
if (partes.length === 3 && partes[1] === 'rows' && partes[2] === 'returned.') {
    if (isNaN(partes[0])) {
        console.log(`valor '${partes[0]}' não é um número`);
    } else {
        let valor = parseInt(partes[0]);
        console.log(`valor=${valor}`);
    }
} else {
    console.log('string não está no formato correto');
}
```

O `split` separa a string por espaços e retorna um array com as partes. Em seguida, basta ver se o array tem 3 partes (o número, a string `rows` e a string `returned.`).

Por fim, eu verifico se é de fato um número, usando a [função `isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), e se for, posso convertê-lo para número, com `parseInt`.

---

#### Quando a string ocorre várias vezes no texto

As soluções acima assumem que você está tratando uma única string, e que ela só pode ter exatamente uma ocorrência de `xxx rows returned.`, e nada mais. Mas se for uma string maior e você quer verificar várias ocorrências desta string, basta mudar o código para:

```js
let texto = `texto blablabla 56 rows returned.
outra linha
mais outra linha com 385 rows returned.
blablabla etc`;
let regex = /(\d+) rows returned\./g;
let match;
while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    let valor = parseInt(match[1]);
    console.log(`valor=${valor}`);
}
```

Eu retirei os marcadores `^` e `$`, pois agora o trecho em questão pode estar em qualquer lugar da string. Eu também uso a [*flag* `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters), que permite buscar todas as ocorrências da regex na string (sem esta *flag*, somente a primeira ocorrência é encontrada).

Em seguida uso o [método `exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), que procura pela próxima ocorrência da string, e daí extraio o respectivo número. Este código pega os dois valores contidos no texto (56 e 385).

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, se o valor `rows returned` é fixo, você pode usar o método `replace` para remove-lo, assim:

```
var str = ('56 rows returned');
var vNumero = parseInt(str.replace('rows returned',''));
```

O valor de `vNumero` será o inteiro `56`.