# Como localizar, recuperar e excluir determinado valor em uma string multiline no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso localizar um valor (possui padrão definido) em um texto, recuperar o mesmo e na sequência excluir o registro.

```
const content = `Exemplo de texto:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an.

2 rows returned.

Lorem!`
```

No texto acima o valor que quero recuperar é: `2 rows returned`.

Condições para rastrear o valor:

- O primeiro caractere da linha será sempre um numero inteiro de
  variável
- Seguido de espaço
- Seguido de 2 a 3 palavras
- finalizado com ponto final ou sinal de exclamação

Obs: o caractere de quebra de linha é `\r\n`

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Um detalhe que não ficou claro: você diz "excluir o registro", isso quer dizer que o trecho em questão deve ser removido da string? De qualquer forma, vamos ver algumas alternativas...*</sup>

---

Se você só quer recuperar a informação da string (os trechos que correspondem ao padrão indicado), uma alternativa é:

```js
const content = `Exemplo de texto:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an.

2 rows returned.

Lorem! Abaixo outro registro

42 the answer!

abaixo registros inválidos
another 2 rows returned
2 rows returned?`;

for (const registro of content.matchAll(/^\d+ \w+ \w+[.!]$/gm)) {
    console.log(`Encontrado: ${registro}`);
}
```

Eu uso os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que *geralmente* indicam o início e fim da string, mas como eu usei a [*flag* `m`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags), isso ativa o modo *multiline* e os marcadores `^` e `$` passam a indicar o início e fim de uma linha. Isso garante que a linha só deve ter o que está indicado na expressão.

Em seguida eu uso `\d+` para "um ou mais dígitos", `\w+` para "um ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos" (e mais abaixo veremos que dá para melhorar isso, se quiser), e no final eu uso a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[.!]`, que significa "um ponto final **ou** uma exclamação".

A regex também usa a *flag* `g` para que ela encontre todas as ocorrências que existirem na string. Sem esta opção, a regex encontraria somente a primeira ocorrência na string.

O código acima encontra os trechos `2 rows returned.` e `42 the answer!`, mas não encontra `2 rows returned?`, por exemplo, pois este não termina com ponto final nem exclamação.

---

Obs: O método `matchAll` [atualmente não é compatível com todos os browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Browser_compatibility). Uma outra alternativa é usar `exec`, que [possui uma compatibilidade melhor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Browser_compatibility):

```js
const content = `Exemplo de texto:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an.

2 rows returned.

Lorem! Abaixo outro registro

42 the answer!

abaixo registros inválidos
another 2 rows returned
2 rows returned?`;

let regex = /^\d+ \w+ \w+[.!]$/gm;
let registro;
while ((registro = regex.exec(content)) !== null) {
    console.log(`Encontrado: ${registro}`);
}
```

---

#### Melhorando a definição de "palavra"

O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` corresponde a letras, números e o caractere `_`, então `\w+` considera que coisas como `_123_`, `1a2b`, `123` e `___` são "palavras".

Se quiser limitar a somente letras, pode trocar `\w+` por `[a-zA-Z]+`, por exemplo, assim a regex só considera letras de `a` a `z`, maiúsculas e minúsculas. Você também poderia usar a *flag* `i` para tornar a regex *case insensitive*, assim ela não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas:

```
let regex = /^\d+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+[.!]$/gmi;
```

Usar um ou outro depende de como estão os seus dados. Se há chances de falsos positivos usando `\w`, prefira [ser o mais específico possível](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) e só colocar o que de fato você quer capturar.

Quanto aos números, em outra pergunta sua [eu já respondi dando outras opções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/407790/112052), caso queira ser mais específico.

---

#### Sobre "excluir o registro"

Se você quis dizer que quer excluir estes trechos da string, uma forma de fazer seria:

```js
const content = `Exemplo de texto:
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an.

2 rows returned.

Lorem! Abaixo outro registro

42 the answer!

abaixo registros inválidos
another 2 rows returned
2 rows returned?`;

console.log(content.replace(/^\d+ \w+ \w+[.!]$/gm, ''));
```

O `replace` acima usa a mesma regex para substituir o trecho encontrado por uma string vazia. O detalhe é que os marcadores `^` e `$` só marcam posições da string (o início e final da linha), mas eles não incluem os caracteres `\n` e `\r`, então eles permanecem na string. Se quiser removê-los, basta inclui-los na regex:

```
console.log(content.replace(/^\d+ \w+ \w+[.!]\r\n/gm, ''));
```

Assim, toda a linha contendo o número e as duas palavras é removida, incluindo os próprios `\r` e `\n`.